# How to resolve cloud functions time out error?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

```
import json
import base64
from google.cloud import bigquery
import ast
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pandas_gbq


def process_data(data):
    #msg = str(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Data":data},index=[0])
    df['time'] = pd.datetime.now()
    lst = list(df)
    df[lst] = df[lst].astype(str)
    pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df,'datasetid.tableid',project_id='project_id',if_exists='append')


def receive_messages(project_id, subscription_name):
    """Receives messages from a pull subscription."""
    # [START pubsub_subscriber_async_pull]
    # [START pubsub_quickstart_subscriber]
    import time

    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    # TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
    # TODO subscription_name = "Your Pub/Sub subscription name"

    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    # The `subscription_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
    # in the form `projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_name}`
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project_id, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        #print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
        process_data(message)
        message.ack()

    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

    # The subscriber  is non-blocking. We must keep the main thread from
    # exiting to allow it to process messages asynchronously in the background.
   # print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
    # [END pubsub_subscriber_async_pull]
    # [END pubsub_quickstart_subscriber]


receive_messages(project-id,sub-id)
```

I'm streaming the real time data from Pub/Sub to bigquery using cloud functions.

Here the following error:

Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: function load attempt timed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is in a `while True` loop. Cloud Functions considers that your code has crashed because it does not return. Then your function is killed.

Redesign so that Pub/Sub is calling your Cloud Function using events (triggers). Follow this guide on how to implement a correct design:

[Google Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions_calling_pubsub-python)